# TFS2008 Bad Branch Created

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

I've created a branch with TFS2008: Over a folder named Main, I've created a branch called Dev, and all works fine, in the Dev folder there's all code from Main.

But when I've started to work with Dev folder I've seen a child folder called Main, and I don't know how it has been created (in the same moment that I created the Dev branch).

This is the structure:

- $/Project

  - Main

    - [Files]
  - Dev

    - [Files]
    - Main

      - [Files]

When I try to delete $/Project/Dev/Main, later when I merge changes from Dev, tfs marks $/Project/Main as pending to delete.

In summary, is there any way to delete the link between  $/Project/Dev/Main and $/Project/Main? The files in $/Project/Dev can merge fine with $/Project/Main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a tricky way to solve my problem:

- Move $/Project/Dev/Main to $/Project/BadMainBranch
- Delete $/Project/BadMainBranch and check-in.

Problem solved... but if anybody could show another way to solve it, perhaps I'll can understand what happens really!

Comment: I think that your first problem is related to the first creation of main, you've just forgot to check-in your first creation, at least I can reproduce this behaviour like that.